# Multidimensional Array Doing Multiple but needing all items in a single array

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, coldfusion

I'm developing a player price tracking function that returns 50 results per request, and I'm sending 8 requests - so I'll be getting 400 results back.

I want to have all 400 results in a multi-dimensional array (as I want to have one element that stores the player's rating and another that will store the price) and have the functionality up to a point.

```
// DEFAULT VARIABLES
Variables.binArray = arrayNew(1);
Variables.startPosition = 0;

// LOOP 8x50 TIMES = 400 CARDS
for (i=1; i <= 8; i++) {
    // DO SEARCH
    Variables.searchPlayer = Application.cfcs.Search.doPlayerSearch(URL.assetID,0,"",0,0,0,0,Variables.startPosition,ListLast(Session.pricingAccountPhishingKey,"="),Session.pricingAccountSessionKey);
    if (Variables.searchPlayer.StatusCode EQ "200 OK") {
        Variables.searchResults = DeserializeJSON(Variables.searchPlayer.FileContent);
        Variables.numResults = arrayLen(Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo);
        // IF MORE THAN ONE RESULT RETURNED
        if (StructKeyExists(Variables,"numResults") AND Variables.numResults GT 0) {
            // LOOP ROUND RESULTS
            for (j=1; j<=Variables.numResults; j++) {
                // SET BIN PRICE FROM LOWEST CARD
                if (Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].itemData.assetID EQ URL.assetID AND Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].buyNowPrice GT 0 AND Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].sellerName NEQ "Mendoza Juniors") {
                    binArray[j] = arrayNew(1);
                    binArray[j][1] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].itemData.rating;
                    binArray[j][2] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].buyNowPrice;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // INCREASE START POSITION
    Variables.startPosition = Variables.startPosition + 50;
}
```

As you can see I have an initial loop that will send the 8 requests and within each iteration I have another loop that loops round all returned results and adds them to the array.

My problem is that I am only getting the last 50 results returned in my array rather than the 400.

How do I amend my code so that all 400 results are stored in the one array?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting binArray on each j loop, so binArray[j] is always going to be 1 on it's first loop pass even when the i loop is greater then 1. You need to find the array length first.

So try changing this:

```
binArray[j] = arrayNew(1);
binArray[j][1] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].itemData.rating;
binArray[j][2] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].buyNowPrice;
```

to this:

```
jj = ArrayLen(binArray)+1;
binArray[jj] = arrayNew(1);
binArray[jj][1] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].itemData.rating;
binArray[jj][2] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].buyNowPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat binArray as a 3D array.

```
if (Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].itemData.assetID EQ URL.assetID AND Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].buyNowPrice GT 0 AND Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[i].sellerName NEQ "Mendoza Juniors") {
      binArray[i][j] = arrayNew(1);
      binArray[i][j][1] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].itemData.rating;
      binArray[i][j][2] = Variables.searchResults.auctionInfo[j].buyNowPrice;
}
```

This should create an array that ends up like this:

```
[1..8][1..50][1..2]
```

Comment: Will this not create 8 arrays?

Comment: no, it updates only 1 array.  As it is, you currently re-create binArray 8 times

Comment: TBH, I question whether a multi-dimensional array is the correct data structure to use here. Surely `binArray[j]` (in the original code) should be a struct keyed on `rating` and `buyNowPrice`, not an array indexed on `1` and `2`..?

Comment: I've actually changed the approach altogether and am now adding the results to a query as I need to get the lowest price for each individual rating so using QoQs allows me to do this

Comment: Unless you need data that is not associated with the lowest priced item, maybe you should change your approach event more so that you don't waste resources on stuff you don't need.

Comment: Adam and Dan are right on it being the wrong structure for the data, but unless I'm being dense this answer isn't right - a multi-dimensional 3D array is created with a _single_ call to ArrayNew with the argument being the number of dimensions - i.e. `ArrayNew(3)` - and there should not be a `binArray[i][j] = arrayNew(1)` line inside the inner loop.

Comment: @DanBracuk The data that is not associated with the lowest priced item is not required but I cannot think of another approach other than maybe setting a variable in the first loop and then only ever re-setting that value if a lower priced item is found, but I don't think that would help when I'm dealing with multiple low prices (lowest price per that rating)?

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand, but you can potentially do something along the lines of `LowestPrice[Rating] = min( LowestPrice[Rating] , CurrentPrice )` ?